# Complete terminal control on android

Tags: android, linux, terminal

I have been trying to run a few Linux commands on my android phone with

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

And noticed that I can only run specific commands and get the proper output even if the device is rooted with SuperSU (I have also tested it with a device without SuperSU on it).

For example, if I run `ls` and try to put it on a screen (through a `TextView`) as follows:

```
public void onBtnClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText commandLine = findViewById(R.id.commandText);
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.getText().toString());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView)).setText(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView)).getText() + "\n" + in.readLine());
        commandLine.setText("");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the output is `acct` which makes sense. 

But on the other  hand, if lets say I run `pwd` it gives me the following error:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command:
>   [pwd] Working Directory: null Environment: null

I did some research online and stumbled upon [Termux](https://termux.com/) that can have complete control over the phone through a terminal which is exactly what I'm looking to make (for my own learning and testing purposes).
And although it's just an emulator it can do exactly what I want but the only problem is that it requires I input the commands through the terminal.

What I'm here for is to sort of replicate what Termux does for myself so that I could run Linux commands properly from the Java code of the application, not requiring the user to actually input commands.

Can anyone help me with where to start and the basics of running those commands properly on my device?

Comment: Since [Termux is open source](https://github.com/termux/termux-app), you could look at how Termux does it.

Comment: My expectation is that you're running into commands that aren't implemented by a program, but by the shell.  And since you aren't running a shell, those commands don't exist.  Solutions are to implement them yourself, or run a shell first and pip the commands through that.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh wow... how did I miss that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Termux states that it doesn't work as a traditional Linux bash does since it sets its own virtual-ish environment when first setting up in its data directory in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr see [here](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
Also, according to [the official android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime()), the `exec(command)` method,

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
>
> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(command)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation exec(command, null,
>   null).

So if it's a separate process, when executing a command, it will run it inside that process' directory (Each process in Linux gets its directory and is assigned an PID which os uses). So what the `ls` command gives you is simply whatever's inside that process' directory. You should be somewhere like `/proc/31415/` and there's only a `acct` file (cgroup in regular Linux).

What you should be doing is running the command inside a directory by declaring it when invoking getRuntime().exec() see the link above to find the right one you'll need. I'd suggest using the override which handles all the parameters.
You'll need something like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"mkdir", "testDir"};
File env =  new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, env);
```

Also, it doesn't hurt to take a look at Termux's [installer code](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/blob/063ef02f2b5b95efc5961d4fbe90e8196f1bbc5e/app/src/main/java/com/termux/app/TermuxInstaller.java) (exec(). It'll give you a good overlook to setting up your environment as well as working with basic commands.

Also, I think you've done it already but double check to make sure that you're requesting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for your application.

Comment: Thank you! fantastic answer!

Comment: @ElyShaffir also makes sure about commands that you want to run , the can harm user device badly